# Considering convex set minus a vector to find the distance between convex set and vector

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

This question concerns a step in the proof theorem 2.5. from Conway's Course in Functional Analysis. The theorem is:

If $H$ is a Hilbert space and $K$ a closed convex nonempty subset, then for any vector $h\in H$ there is a unique point $k_0$ in $K$ such that $\vert\vert h -k_0\vert\vert = \text{dist}(h,K) = \text{inf}\{\vert\vert h-k \vert\vert : k\in K \} $.

The proof starts by saying that by considering $K-h := \{k-h : k\in K \}$ instead of $K$ it suffices to assume $h=0$. I am confused why we are allowed to do this or why it allows us to assume $h=0$, since I don't see any reason why $\text{dist}(h,K-h) = \text{inf}\{\vert\vert h-k-h\vert\vert \} = \text{inf}\{\vert\vert k \vert\vert \}$ would be equal to $\text{dist}(h,K)$ in general. I'm clearly missing something.

Comment: It’s actually that $\mathrm{dist}(0, K - h) = \mathrm{dist}(h, K)$. This tells you that, instead of trying to find $k_0 \in K$ that minimizes the distance from $h$, you can instead find $k_0’ \in K - h$ that minimizes the distance from $0$. Then you can just set $k_0 = k_0’ + h$.

Comment: And $K-h$ is stll closed,  convex and nonempty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\{x : x\in K-h\} = \{ k-h : k\in K \}$, it follows that
$$\{\|x\| : x\in K-h \} = \{ \|k-h\| : k \in K \}$$
which implies, as stated in the comments, that $\text{dist}(0,K-h) = \text{dist}(h,K)$.

If the theorem has been proved in the case where $h = 0$, then for the general case, it can be verified that $K-h$ is a closed and convex set. So there exists a unique $x_{0}\in K-h$ such that $\|x_{0}\| = \inf \{\|x\| : x \in K-h \}$. Then there is a $k_{0}\in K$ such that $x_{0} = k_{0} - h$. Then
$$\|k_{0} - h\| = \|x_{0}\| = \inf \{ \|x\| : x\in K-h \} = \inf \{ \|k-h\| : k\in K \}.$$

It can further be verified that $k_{0}$ is unique. Therefore, $k_{0}$ is the unique member of $K$ such that $\|h - k_{0}\| = \text{dist}(h,K)$.

Comment: You probably want to say $K - h$ is a closed and convex set without the “containing the zero vector” part?

Comment: @DavidGao Thanks for mentioning this. I corrected the answer.